# Rounding the mean of difftime

Tags: r, data.table, rounding, difftime

In my R data.table mdt below, I have calculated a difference in dates using subtraction (simple mathematical expression) as days_elapsed1 and days_elapsed2. The class of these two objects is "difftime" expressed in days. Then, I take the mean of days_elapsed1 and days_elapsed2 across groups. The mean is also a difftime result expressed in days, but I cannot figure out how to round the difftime result. As simple as this seems, could anyone please provide an answer in base R or data.table? I'm relatively new to R.

Please note I'm avoiding the use of dplyr as I am trying to keep everything in data.table language.

Below is a reproducible example. I know there are a few more things here than needed, but it was far simpler for me to edit an existing example -- that earlier took me a long time to produce -- than reproduce another. My code uses brute force because I am new to R.

```
# Create a sample data set
library(data.table)
tests <- c("test1", "test2")
prob_bucket <- c(0.5, 0.3)
person_id <- sample(101:110, size=30, replace=TRUE)
grp <- sample(0:1, size = 30, replace = TRUE)
month <- sample(1:12, size=30, replace=TRUE)
day <- sample(1:28, size=30, replace=TRUE)
year <- sample(2018:2022, size=30, replace=TRUE)
test <- sample(tests, 30, replace=TRUE, prob = prob_bucket)
mydt <- data.table(person_id, grp, month, day, year, test)
mydt[, test_date:= as.Date(paste(month, day, year, sep = "-"), 
                           format="%m-%d-%Y")]
mydt[test_date < as.Date("02-01-2019", format="%m-%d-%Y"), grp:=0]
mydt[test_date >= as.Date("02-01-2019", format="%m-%d-%Y"), grp:=1]
mydt[, grp := as.factor(grp)]
ss_a <- mydt[test=="test1"]
ss_b <- mydt[test=="test2"]
a <- round(runif(nrow(ss_a), 5.5, 8),1)
b <- sample(100:250, size=nrow(ss_b), replace=TRUE)
mydt[test=="test1", ind_test1:=1][test=="test1", test_value:=a]
mydt[test=="test2", ind_test2:=1][test=="test2", test_value:=b]
setorder(mydt, cols = "person_id", "grp")

# Identify critical values test1
mydt[ind_test1==1, critical_date_test1:= max(test_date), by=.(person_id, grp)]
mydt[, critical_date_test1:=mean(critical_date_test1, na.rm=TRUE), by=.(person_id, grp)]
mydt[test_date==critical_date_test1, critical_value_test1:= test_value]
mydt[, critical_value_test1:=mean(critical_value_test1, na.rm=TRUE), by=.(person_id, grp)]

# Identify critical values test2
mydt[ind_test2==1, critical_date_test2:= max(test_date), by=.(person_id, grp)]
mydt[, critical_date_test2:=mean(critical_date_test2, na.rm=TRUE), by=.(person_id, grp)]
mydt[test_date==critical_date_test2, critical_value_test2:= test_value]
mydt[, critical_value_test2:=mean(critical_value_test2, na.rm=TRUE), by=.(person_id, grp)]

# Days elapsed between fixed date and critical test dates
fixed_date <-as.Date("2-1-2019", format="%m-%d-%Y")
mydt[grp==0, days_elapsed1 := fixed_date-critical_date_test1]
mydt[grp==1, days_elapsed1 := critical_date_test1-fixed_date]
mydt[grp==0, days_elapsed2 := fixed_date-critical_date_test2]
mydt[grp==1, days_elapsed2 := critical_date_test2-fixed_date]

# Collapse data
dt_summ1_collapsed <- mydt[, .SD[1], by=.(person_id, grp)] 
days_elapsed <- c("days_elapsed1", "days_elapsed2")
# Take the mean across people in the collapsed data set, by grp
dt_summ_collapsed2 <- dt_summ1_collapsed[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), 
                                         by=grp, .SDcols=days_elapsed]

# Two different attempts to round the result
dt_summ_collapsed2[, .SD:=round(.SD, 0), .SDcols=days_elapsed]
dt_summ_collapsed2[, .SD:=round_date(.SD, "day"), .SDcols=days_elapsed]
```

Comment: It would help immensely to see your data, please post the output from `dput(head(mydt,20))` (enough rows to matter) into a [code block]. For starters, this is a simple difference-of-dates-by-group: `data.table(grp=sample(c("A","B"),20,replace=TRUE),date=sort(Sys.Date()+sort(runif(20,0,200))))[,datediff:=c(diff(date),0)][,round(datediff,0),grp]`

Comment: Yes, I understand. I've edited my post to include a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `round_date()` expects the input to be dates/ difference of dates. However, the columns of `days_elapsed1` and `days_elapsed2` are numeric values.

It should work if you replace the last line with the following:

```
dt_summ_collapsed2[, (n_days):=round(.SD), .SDcols=n_days]
```

**Update on 18 April 2023, based on updated question featuring example**

**Method 1: Use a different function while calculating mean**

```
RoundMean <- function(x){
  
  Results <- round(mean(x, na.rm = T), 0)
  return(Results)
  
}

dt_summ_collapsed2 <- dt_summ1_collapsed[, lapply(.SD, RoundMean), 
                                         by=grp, .SDcols=days_elapsed]
```

**Method 2: Update columns on rounding one by one**

```
dt_summ_collapsed2[, days_elapsed1 := round(days_elapsed1, 0)]
dt_summ_collapsed2[, days_elapsed2 := round(days_elapsed2, 0)]
```

Comment: @sunflower Thanks for the elaboration. I have updated my answer accordingly. Hope it helps! Also, it may not matter in this case, but for reproducible example, often it helps to set.seed() before doing any random sampling.

Comment: TheN: Thank you so much for updating your solution. I'm not sure why your method #2, which I thought I tried earlier, did not work earlier. Likely there was some other issue lurking in the attributes of the objects that I had created earlier with a different block of code. Previously, it seemed strange that applying the round function (or a round_date function) to a "difftime" variable did not work. I also had tried adding the round function to lapply, and had no luck there either. All good reasons to have an example ready for all questions! Thank you for easing my near constant R struggles.